# SQL Server : copy data without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

How do you transfer the contents of a (potentially large) table from a local database to a remotely hosted one with regards to the following

- no duplicate entries are allowed in the target table
- the data traffic should be kept to a minimum

?

Locally I have SQL Server Express, on the remote host: SQL Server Standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how "far away" your hosting provider is (-->bandwidth) it is generally not a good idea to run queries involving tables from both databases although technically this is possible using MSSQL-studio.

My advice: upload the whole lot from your local table (say `tbl`) into a server table named `tmptbl` and then do the inserting on the remote system with the following command

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id,col1,col2,col3, ...) 
SELECT id,col1,col2,col3, ... FROM tmptbl WHERE id NOT IN (
 SELECT id FROM tbl
)
```

After that you can `DROP` the import table `tmptbl`again ...
This example assumes that `id` identifies uniquely your records. I still named all columns explicitely just in case there is a further `auto_increment`-ed `PRIMARY KEY` in each table.

**Edit:**

Alternatively it is (theoretically) possible to apply the above statement directly between the tables of the two servers by linking the remote one using `sp_addlinkedserver`, see [MSSQL manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259589%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). I have tried that too in the past but found that due to the limited bandwidth between the servers the performance was **extremely** bad, especially when it comes to larger tables.

Comment: I know this way, I was just wondered if there any other option, may be it's posssible by using Import/Export Data dialog in SSMS or it TSQL (copy between different servers, not only between tables)

Comment: I also experimented quite a bit with various SSMS import options but in the end the described version always worked best for me, mainly because of the limited bandwidth restriction between the two database servers. It is always most efficient to do subqueries or JOINs within one database.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation

Comment: Btw, for anyone interested, now this functionality built-in into Visual Studio 2013 Professional. So we can copy data from local/test DB server to prod with different merging/overriding/etc options